# PHP Proxy Script for Indirect Browsing

Tags: php, http, proxy

I'm looking for a PHP script that I can install on my own server that allows indirect HTTP browsing with my server as a proxy.  I want it to automatically convert all tags within document to redirect to my server as well, so that once I'm on a site, I can still click through any of the links and see all images.

In the past I've used http://www.jmarshall.com/tools/cgiproxy/ which is amazing and does exactly what I want, but for my current purposes, I need a PHP script that does that same (or similar) function.

I was planning on spending time converting the above CGI proxy script to PHP, but thought I'd ask around before reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Why not use mod_rewrite with [P]? Works for most websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [phpproxy from freshmeat.net](http://freshmeat.net/projects/phpproxy/), or perhaps [this google-code project](http://code.google.com/p/php-web-proxy/).